# Django App URL model not importing

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Im certain that this is something simply that Im overlooking but Im too irritated to figure it out alone so thanks in advance.

**Project Directory Structure**
**UPDATED**

```
myproject/
  manage.py
  myproject/
    apps/
      geo/
        urls.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from django.contrib.gis import admin

admin.autodiscover()

from pinax.apps.account.openid_consumer import PinaxConsumer

handler500 = "pinax.views.server_error"

urlpatterns = patterns("",
url(r"^$", direct_to_template, {'template' : 'home.html' }, name="home"),
url(r"^admin/invite_user/$", "pinax.apps.signup_codes.views.admin_invite_user", name="admin_invite_user"),
url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r"^about/", include("apps.about.urls")),
url(r"^account/", include("pinax.apps.account.urls")),
url(r"^openid/", include(PinaxConsumer().urls)),
url(r"^profiles/", include("idios.urls")),
url(r"^notices/", include("notification.urls")),
url(r"^announcements/", include("announcements.urls")),
url(r"^products/", include("products.urls")),
url(r"^locate/", include("geo.urls")),
url(r"^sectors/", include("sectors.urls")),
)


if settings.SERVE_MEDIA:
    urlpatterns += patterns("",
        url(r"", include("staticfiles.urls")),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# project
"tulsa-site.apps.about",
"tulsa-site.apps.profiles",
"tulsa-site.apps.geo",
"tulsa-site.apps.sectors",
]
```

When I go to the url path "http://127.0.0.1:8000/locate/" is receive the error message: I recieve the exception value "No module named geo.urls." What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't be something like `url(r"^locate/", include("apps.geo.urls")),` ?

Comment: Nah, I tried that one already but it didnt work.

Comment: FYI: read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py which explains the new project layout. It is better to have apps on the same level as `manage.py` since this way way are more portable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include("geo.urls")` tells Django to look for `geo.urls` relative to the `manage.py` file. So  its essentially looking for this file:

```
myproject/
  manage.py
  myproject/
    apps/
    settings.py
    urls.py
  geo/
    urls.py <- this file
```

That is sort of the new directory structure starting with Django 1.4 which encourages to have apps independent of the Django project. However if you still follow the old layout where the apps folders are within the project folder, then you have to change your imports to reflect that:

```
include("myproject.geo.urls")
```

**EDIT**

Following your updated layout:

```
include("myproject.apps.geo.urls")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r"^locate/", include("tulsa-site.apps.geo.urls"))
```